# Why is my iReport throwing me ORA-00932:inconsistent datatypes:expected number got DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting

I have a problem that I can not solve. I have three parameters on iReport and data query. Everything seems fine but I can not compile it. I am using iReport 2.03. Please help.

Comment: Expected number got DATE. I guess you try calculate average value on datetime column. `select avg(sysdate) from dual`

Comment: could you please provide datatypes for your parameters?